# Converting a float to the integer with the same bit representation as it, in java?

Tags: java, pointers, floating-point, binary, integer

I think this is not hard in C with pointers. However, how would one do this in java? EG a float is represented as 101001, and you want the integer represented by 101001 (obviously shortened since they're really 32 bits)? Just curious.

Comment: As they say, [RTFM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToRawIntBits%28float%29) -- (Read The Fantastic Manual)

Comment: How have the ways you've tried it so far been failing?

Comment: It is highly unlikely you have a float which is `101001` in binary or decimal and I assume this is a made up example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want [Float.floatToIntBits()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToIntBits%28float%29).

Comment: Or `Float.floatToRawIntBits()`